# Bootstrap Date time picker ,selection on arrow keys not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui

Am using Bootstrap datetimepicker , and my requirement is i should be able to select time icon from date screen to go to time screen and again click on date icon to come back to date selection screen using KEYS(arrow keys). Am able to navigate between dates and time (up/down keys) with arrow keys but not able to select the time icon , date icon and AM/PM with this datetimepicker.

Can anyone help me with a js fiddle will be highly appreciated

Am using

bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js Version 4.3.1

jquery.min.css version 3.5.1

bootstrap-datetimepicker.css and bootstrap-datetimepicker.js version-3.1.1

moment.js version : 2.8.1

Thanks